# Tosca execution error unable to open workspace

Tags: testing, error-handling, automation, automated-tests, tosca

I have a Tosca test case for cicking on the automobile in tricentis sample web application.
I have executed the same in Tosca CI and it works.
Now, I want to run it on a CMD. I have navigated to the path where Toscaclient is present and ran the below command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCommander\ToscaCI\Client>ToscaCIClient.exe -m local -c Automobile.xml -r results.xml

it throws an error as below:
Inner Exception:
Tricentis.TCCore.Base.WorkspaceFileUnloadableException: Workspace 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCommander\ToscaCI\ClientC:\TOSCA_PROJECTS\TOSCA_Workspace\Test\Test.tws' could not be loaded ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Workspace-File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TRICENTIS\Tosca Testsuite\ToscaCommander\ToscaCI\ClientC:\TOSCA_PROJECTS\TOSCA_Workspace\Test\Test.tws' not found!

where as, I can see the Test.tws is present in this location:
C:\TOSCA_PROJECTS\TOSCA_Workspace\Test\Test.tws'

Am not sure, why the path is showing by appending to the client location.
Note: Toscaclient.exe config has this path only as workspace location.
C:\TOSCA_PROJECTS\TOSCA_Workspace\Test\Test.tws

could someone help?